# How to show a user's friends with only the Views and Flag module?

Tags: views, flags

Is it possible to show user's friends on a user's page (located `user/%/friends`) with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) by using only [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module? So without the [Flag Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_friend) module or any other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1:

Use the [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module to create a flag labeled "Friend" (or something like that). Here is such Flag definition (in export format) you could use for it (just import it in your own site):

```
$flags = array();
// Exported flag: "Friend".
$flags['friend'] = array (
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'title' => 'Friend',
  'global' => '0',
  'types' => 
  array (
  ),
  'flag_short' => 'Friend',
  'flag_long' => 'Mark as friend',
  'flag_message' => 'User marked as friend',
  'unflag_short' => 'Unfriend',
  'unflag_long' => 'Remove as friend',
  'unflag_message' => 'User removed as friend',
  'unflag_denied_text' => '',
  'link_type' => 'toggle',
  'weight' => 0,
  'show_in_links' => 
  array (
    'full' => 'full',
  ),
  'show_as_field' => 0,
  'show_on_form' => 0,
  'access_author' => '',
  'show_contextual_link' => 0,
  'show_on_profile' => 1,
  'access_uid' => 'others',
  'api_version' => 3,
);
return $flags;
```

## Step 2:

Use the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a view of users that flagged other users with that "Friend" flag.  Here is such view (in export format) you could use for it (just import it in your own site):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'my_friends';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'My friends';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Friends';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: Flags: friend */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'friend';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Last login */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['id'] = 'login';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['field'] = 'login';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['login']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Field: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: Flags: Flagged time */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user/%/friends';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Friends';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['description'] = 'Users marked as friends';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'user-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
```

## Result

After you enable the view, the result of it is that it'll show a tabular list of users, via path `user/%/friends`, and it will add a "***Friends***" tab on the user profile page (also).

Here is a sample of such table:

```
Name           ! Last login                  ! Uid
---------------+-----------------------------+----
Dries.Buytaert ! Monday, May 2, 2016 - 18:19 ! 19
Demo.User      ! Friday, May 6, 2016 - 12:16 ! 8
```

Comment: I would like to precise that this view must be seen by other users.

Comment: I suppose that Flags: friends (by any user) must be used instead of 
Flags: friends (by current user) in this case?

Comment: To "see this view by other users", that should work too ... All that's needed would be to replace the "**x**" in the path like "user/x/friends" to the "**uid**" of the user for which you want to see that user's friend. Or am I missing something? PS: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your 2nd comment is not correct (or otherwise I don't understand it). Let me know, ok?

Comment: I mean that other users would be able to see another user's friends. For this view a user can only see his/her own friends.

Comment: @gladiatorhl2: I'm still not sure I understand what you would "like" to happen ... If I'm "demo.user" (as in my "result"), I could use a path like user/19/friends (to see the friends from user "Dries.Buytaert"). Agree? If so: is that what you would "want", or do you NOT want to "allow" that?

Comment: Yes, I would like to allow all the users to see each other's friends. If we use this view, a demo.user see only his own friends and it doesn't depend on user/%/friends (for example, user/1/friends or user/2/friends he/she sees only his/her own friends but not % user's friends). What kind of condition must be added to have this result? I mean that on user/1/friends another user would see 1's friends and on user/2/friends 2's friends but not his/her own friends?

Comment: How about you ***expose*** the filter? Would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a contextual filter to the User uid on the flag.

Comment: Could you indicate what this action is needed for?